# Pesquisa em vetor - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, funções, recursão

Estou construindo uma função que faz uma pesquisa linear num arranjo. O que eu gostaria é que em vez de deixar na chamada o valor do tamanho do arranjo, gostaria de usar a propriedade `length` para que ela mesmo possa calcular o seu tamanho e assim fazer a chamada. Só que sempre que coloco o `vet.length` dá o erro `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, mas se eu colocar o 6 na chamada dá certo.

O que fazer?

```
public static int buscaValor(int vet[], int maximo, int value) {

    if (maximo >= 0) {
        if (vet[maximo] == value) //(linha 9)
            return maximo;
        else
            return buscaValor(vet, maximo - 1, value);
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vet[] = {10, 2, 43, 14, 25, 6, 37};
    System.out.print("\n\nQual valor deseja buscar? - ");
    int respostaBusca = read.nextInt();
    int index = buscaValor(vet, vet.length, respostaBusca); //(linha 22)

    if (index == -1)
        System.out.println("Elemento não encontrado");
    else
        System.out.println("O índice do elemento " + respostaBusca + " é: " + index);
}
```

O erro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>     at buscavalor.BuscaValor.buscaValor(BuscaValor.java:9)
>     at buscavalor.BuscaValor.main(BuscaValor.java:22)
> ```

Comment: O erro ocorre o método buscaLinear, adicione este método na pergunta.

Comment: @Articuno Na verdade é tudo buscaValor, foi um erro meu na hora de copiar. Já editado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em particular, `vet.length` é 7 (há 7 elementos). Se você passar como parâmetro 6, funciona. O motivo disso é por que na forma como você fez, ao passar `vet.length` (7), o método `buscaValor` vai tentar acessar o array na posição 7, mas as posições só vão de 0 a 6. As posições de um array em Java sempre vão de 0 até `array.length - 1`.

Assim sendo, a solução é trocar `vet.length` por `vet.length - 1`.

Comment: Nossa, havia me esquecido completamente disso. Obrigado.

Comment: @AndersonLessa Se não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida acerca desta pergunta, clique no ✅ que aparece abaixo do número de votação desta resposta para marcá-la como aceita e marcar a sua pergunta como resolvida. Foi um prazer ajudá-lo. 